# Sign the XML document Digitally in the Windows store App

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, xml-signature

I want to digitally sign the XML file available in the Local app data to be signed, So that I can ensure that the value in the file is not tampered. I have used VS2017 with SDK version 16299. Still I was unable to get the right way to sign the xml document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataProtectionProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241559) class to asynchronously encrypt and decrypt static data or a data stream.

You can read the data from the xml document then encrypt and save the data into a file, when you want to use the file, you can also decrypt the file using above class. See the [Data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/data-protection) topic.